# If it is a good graph to show the relationship between the training error and test error after using optim function?

Tags: r, classification, optimization, validation

[image]
[image]
**The following is code for optimization, during which I calculate the validation error(or test error) too.But I am not sure whether it is a good graph or if there is some problems with my code.Please give me some suggestions.**

**code**

```r
colnames(data_plot)[3] <- "CellType"
    

n <- nrow(data_plot)
set.seed(12345)
id <- sample(1:n,floor(n * 0.5))
data_train <- data_plot[id,]
data_test <- data_plot[-id,]


data_train$CellType <- ifelse(data_train$CellType == "T-cell",1,-1)
data_test$CellType <- ifelse(data_test$CellType == "T-cell",1,-1)

data_train_p <- as.matrix(data_train[,-3])
data_test_p <- as.matrix(data_test[,-3])

lossfun <- function(theta,X, Y){
  result <- mean(log(1 + exp(-Y * (X %*%theta))))
  return(result)
}

cost <- function(theta){
  loss_train <- lossfun(theta,X = data_train_p,Y = data_train$CellType)
  loss_test <- lossfun(theta,X= data_test_p,Y = data_test$CellType)
  
  num <<- num + 1
  training_cost[num] <<- loss_train
  test_cost[num] <<- loss_test
  
  return(loss_train)
  
}

num <- 0
training_cost <- NULL
test_cost <- NULL


theta_initial <- rep(0,2)
optimum_theta <- optim(par = theta_initial,fn = cost,method = "BFGS",control=list(maxit=20))

iteration <- 1:num
data_plot <- data.frame(iteration,training_cost,test_cost)
data_plot <- reshape2::melt(data_plot,id.var = "iteration")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_plot,aes(x=iteration,y= value,color= variable)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: It definitely doesn't look good, your test error keeps increasing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I just make some modifications to my code and get the result like the new graph. Could you tell me how about this one?